# How to use LEN function in Left join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Positions.Issuer_Name
    FROM
     Positions
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
              [Assetid]
            FROM
                Report
        ) Report ON
            Report.[Assetid] = Positions.CUSIP //here instead of Report.[Assetid] i need to use `"right([Assetid], Len([Assetid])-1)"`
```

i need to use `"right([Assetid], Len([Assetid])-1)"` this which remove 1st letter and compare `"Positions.CUSIP"`

which is the better way to write this ?

instead of writing like

`" ) Report ON
            Report.right([Assetid], Len([Assetid])-1) = Positions.CUSIP"`

should i declare variable and do `"right([Assetid], Len([Assetid])-1)"` first but how can i use it in JOIN then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do, do you want to compare based on the `right()` value at that point or do you want the `right()` value prior to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Issuer_Name
FROM Positions p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Right([Assetid], Len(Assetid)-1) TrimmedAssetid, [Assetid]
    FROM Report
) r 
    ON r.TrimedAssetid = p.CUSIP
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Issuer_Name
FROM Positions p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Assetid]
    FROM Report
) r 
    ON Right(r.Assetid,  Len(r.Assetid)-1)) = Positions.CUSIP
```

Comment: YES FIRST ATTEMPT IS WHAT I WANT CAN I DECLARE A VARIALE AND SELECT THAT Assetid in that ?
THANKS

Comment: @ashuthinks if you are going to have multiple of these, then you cannot store it in a single variable. You could create a temp table to store all of the values but you would still have to join on it.  The first one is similar in that you are creating a derived table with the value in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

AssetID is a column which you need to use with the Alias

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Positions.Issuer_Name
FROM
 Positions
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          [Assetid]
        FROM
            Report
    ) Report ON
        right(Report.[Assetid], Len(Report.[Assetid])-1) = Positions.CUSIP
```